# Numerical problem in getting the product of two random variables

Tags: random-variables, products

I am using some numerical methods to get the distribution of the product of two random variables.  But if I swap the variables I think of as X and Y, I get different results.  I am trying to figure if this is due to the numerical software, or if I am screwing up in my mathematical thinking.

From Wikipedia, one gets the following result for the pdf of Z = XY, which doesn't seem controversial:

$$f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x) f_Y(\frac{z}{x})\frac{1}{|x|}dx$$

(See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution)

Now, unless I am being thick-headed, X and Y should be interchangeable, so that

$$f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_Y(y) f_X(\frac{z}{y})\frac{1}{|y|}dy$$

But, since both y and x are dummy variables, this should be the same as

$$f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(\frac{z}{x}) f_Y(x)\frac{1}{|x|}dx$$

When I make that change in the code, however, I get a slightly different numerical result.

Am I being dim-witted here, and making some obvious error with all these x's and y's floating around, or is it - as I suspect - a software problem?

Comment: theory makes sense, but perhaps since $f_X$ and $f_Y$ are different you are getting some numerical inconsistency. hard to say without looking at the code...

Comment: If the difference is tiny $<10^{-7}$ for example I would consider a rounding error yes. Every programming language has rounding error when doing operation. It because the results are rounded after many operations

Comment: The error is quite large; a few percent.  But I suspect it is because the actual distributions I am using are quite different in scale; one has a mean of about 1.0 and the other has a mean of about 500,000.  Both are stored, internally, has histograms of discrete values, so suspect the 'sharp corners' and vastly different scale are causing trouble here.  But thanks for reassuring me I haven't done something mathematically stupid.

Comment: It's not a "software" problem.  It's an inherent difficulty of numerical calculation.  You'd have exactly the same problem if you did it with a pencil.

Comment: Really?  I am using Python's scipy package.  They claim to use two separate algos and compare them to bound the error - which is typically reported as an absolute error like $10^{-9}$ and a relative error of $10^{-6}$.  You think this is erroneous?  It sounds like it would need a lot of tuning, or I need to write my own integration software that is smart about the data/problem.

Comment: After much experimentation, it comes down to giving quad() enough 'clues'.  If I use limits of integration that are all positive and extend beyond the necessary range, it gives questionable and unreliable results.  If I limit the range of integration to the range in which I am certain the integrand is non-zero, it works fine with minimal cues,how it uses tuning info  though it helps to give it a 'point' where the maximum leverage, so to speak, is.  Since quad is an old Fortran routine, I would expect to find reference on it.  Any advice on how it uses tuning clues would be appreciated.